# Is it possible to take screenshot of a webbrowser control behind other controls?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am able to take a screenshot of the win form at the location of the webbrowser control and save this screen capture. This method requires that the webbrowser to be on top.

But if the webbrowser is behind another control, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: write code to bring the focus of the web browser to the front would be my best guess

Comment: That works bringing the control to the front then sending it back, but it makes the application lag when you attempt to do this every 2-3 seconds. so I was looking for a possible alternative to do a direct screen capture. on some forums devs stated drawtobitmap works, but that was back a few years back and the it seems to be broken with some controls. .

Comment: [DWM Thumbnail Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may probably want to look at headless webbrowsers like http://phantomjs.org/ it expicitly states ability to take screenshots while being headless (=not shown on screen)

Comment: it has to be showing, I am automating flash for unit testing. then I need to take screenshots after each task is automated. one of the requirements is to have the webbrowser control in the background and statistics of the test upfront at all times.